# Do architecture patterns force a specific folder structures?

Tags: design-patterns

By following an architecture patterns, am I forced to follow a specific file structure? For example if I'm following MVC, am I forced to have a folder structure similar to what asp.net core mvc has?

Don't architecture patterns just tell us how different components should be communicating?

Answer (score 1):

No, Architectural patterns show the logical structure of the application, but the physical structure of the files are not mentioned by the architectural patterns.
Many frameworks enforce some specific folder structure in order the simplify the framework usage, but those are the framework restrictions not the pattern restrictions. For more information about the architectural patterns you can check the POEAA book by Martin Fowler.

Answer (score 1):

Architecture patterns don't force any particular folder structure, but the folder structure in your source tree *is* important, and should be part of your architecture.

Folders should usually be treated as big components, composed of the components defined by the files and sub-folders that they contain.  Each one would therefore be assigned a purpose following the Single Responsibility Principle.

It is specifically an anti-pattern to separate your files into folders based on the types of the files or the types of the artifacts they define -- do not pull all your application's views or all your applications controllers into a separate folder, for example.  Instead, make a folder for the page/window and put its view and controller together in there.

The fact that you decided to use a particular architecture pattern for some component should not be exposed outside of that component.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. Just to make sure I understand correctly, the architecture pattern in that one specific component(your last paragraph) also does NOT require to follow some specific file structure as well. IT JUST NEEDS TO oblige TO concepts/rules of that architecture pattern only right?

Comment: No *particular* folder structure, but an architectural pattern does indicate architectural components of an application.  If those components are bigger than files, then they should generally be folders.  Also, if you use the same pattern in multiple places, it's valuable to use a consistent file structure in all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The Views folder has a different folder for each controller. In our case, all of the .cshtml files that are going to be rendered by the HomeController will be in the Views -> Home folder. If our MVC application had another controller defined (e.g., ArticleController), then the .cshtml files for this controller would have been located in Views -> Article.

Comment: But this is specific to some frameworks. lets put frameworks which come with their FORCED structure out of this equation.